# The new profile drop-downs

Tags: discussion, support, user-card

The new profile only seems to work for the people answering the questions, never for the users modifying the questions, or the users who are asking the questions. Is this a bug?

Also, as an aside, how does this new profile drop-down help improve SE. I'm not quite sure masel.

Comment: Does the user in question have anything in his "about" section? AFAIK the drop down is only displayed if you have more than some minimum number of characters there.

Answer (score 4):

It works also for who edits a question and for who answers. It appears only for users who entered something in the "About Me" field.
There is also a minimum length size for that text; when the text entered in the "About Me" field is shorter than that value, the drop down doesn't appear. This is what seems to happen, for example, for [Saeed Neamati](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/10594/saeed-neamati).

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

---

[image: screenshot]

[image: screnshot]

Comment: (Note the triangles in lower right of Aleananno's & drm65's icon)  There is also a caching issue.  I updated my profile here to include the phrase 'Please send waffles' and it was about 24 hours before the system realized my [About Me] section was long enough.

Comment: Saeed Neamati doesn't have 1000 rep, which is the minimum for getting the popup. @M.Tibbits That shouldn't happen -- can I assume you're describing something that happened a while ago? I fixed the overly aggressive caching about two days ago.